# When LDAP is a requirement for integration but the Directory Services are custom built (Not stored in AD)

Tags: ldap, websphere, adlds

Given there is a requirement from a 3rd party application where LDAP integration is required for authentication, authorization and assignment of users/roles with lookup to directory services or user repository...

When the application environment is Microsoft Server 2012 with WAS to support the application and the server can only access security principals through a web service...

Is there a way to provide LDAP or AD LDS to integrate with the web service or even to sync the local repository with the system of record?

This will probably provide many routes for discussion, but let's assume the application for now can only best subscribe to a LDAP instance for this and AD is not being provided directly to the environment where the application exists AND AD isn't even the system of record - that is exposed from a web service.

Answer (score 0):

This is fundamentally the definition of a meta directory or Virtual directory.

That is, rather than directly contact the directory service for usage, instead there is an abstraction layer, often caching, perhaps uniting data (on the fly per request, or in advance as changes occur).

There are any number of vendors that provide such services in products.